# Remover elementos de arrays em que não estejam em 2 arrays PHP

Tags: php

```
Array A

[0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1542
            [id_restaurant] => 303
            [name] => Café da Manhã
            [hour] => 10:15:00
            [quantity] => 10
            [peoples] => 6
            [weekday] => 1
            [is_available] => 1
            [created_at] => 2018-09-21 16:28:23
            [updated_at] => 2018-09-21 16:28:23
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1543
            [id_restaurant] => 303
            [name] => Almoço
            [hour] => 16:00:00
            [quantity] => 10
            [peoples] => 6
            [weekday] => 1
            [is_available] => 1
            [created_at] => 2018-09-21 16:28:23
            [updated_at] => 2018-09-21 16:28:23
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1544
            [id_restaurant] => 303
            [name] => Janta
            [hour] => 17:45:00
            [quantity] => 10
            [peoples] => 6
            [weekday] => 1
            [is_available] => 1
            [created_at] => 2018-09-21 16:28:23
            [updated_at] => 2018-09-21 16:28:23
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1545
            [id_restaurant] => 303
            [name] => Café da Manhã
            [hour] => 10:45:00
            [quantity] => 20
            [peoples] => 6
            [weekday] => 2
            [is_available] => 1
            [created_at] => 2018-09-21 16:28:23
            [updated_at] => 2018-09-21 16:28:23
        )

Array B

[0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1540
            [id_restaurant] => 303
            [name] => Café da Manhã
            [hour] => 10:15:00
            [quantity] => 10
            [peoples] => 6
            [weekday] => 1
            [is_available] => 1
            [created_at] => 2018-09-21 16:28:23
            [updated_at] => 2018-09-21 16:28:23
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1599
            [id_restaurant] => 303
            [name] => Almoço
            [hour] => 16:00:00
            [quantity] => 10
            [peoples] => 6
            [weekday] => 1
            [is_available] => 1
            [created_at] => 2018-09-21 16:28:23
            [updated_at] => 2018-09-21 16:28:23
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1544
            [id_restaurant] => 303
            [name] => Janta
            [hour] => 17:45:00
            [quantity] => 10
            [peoples] => 6
            [weekday] => 1
            [is_available] => 1
            [created_at] => 2018-09-21 16:28:23
            [updated_at] => 2018-09-21 16:28:23
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1545
            [id_restaurant] => 303
            [name] => Café da Manhã
            [hour] => 10:45:00
            [quantity] => 20
            [peoples] => 6
            [weekday] => 2
            [is_available] => 1
            [created_at] => 2018-09-21 16:28:23
            [updated_at] => 2018-09-21 16:28:23
        )
```

Tenho 2 arrays A e B... preciso remover de ambos os arrays os elementos cujo os id não estejam em ambos os arrays A e B ex: os ids 1544 e 1545 existem em ambos os arrays, os que não existem preciso remover de ambos os arrays.

Comment: Sua pergunta ficou confusa, pelo que eu entendi, você quer remover dos dois `array` os itens que não existem nos dois `array`. Monta um exemplo do retorno que você precisa e coloca também o código que já tentou.

Comment: pronto agora ta funcionando.... não tinha reparado que vc queria separar os que existem nos 2

Comment: ae man valida a resposta ae pra quem precisar saber qual foi usada

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Comparação de array objeto

```
$array1 = array(
    (object) array("id" => 1),
    (object) array("id" => 3),
    (object) array("id" => 5),
    (object) array("id" => 6),
    (object) array("id" => 7)
);

$array2 = array(
    (object) array("id" => 1),
    (object) array("id" => 3),
    (object) array("id" => 5),
    (object) array("id" => 6),
    
);

$array3 = array();
foreach($array2 as $t) {
    $array3[] = $t->id;
}
$result = array_filter($array1, function($v) use($array3){
    return in_array($v->id, $array3);
});
print_r($result);
```

[Veja funcionando](https://ideone.com/ECmIYn)

Answer (score 0):

Caso seus vetores não sejam objetos você pode
utilizar o [**array_intersect**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-intersect.php) que calcula a interseção entre arrays.
Retorna um array contendo todos os valores de `array1` que estão presentes nos outros argumentos. **Note que as chaves são preservadas**.
Podes ver funcionando [aqui](https://www.ideone.com/dzatAy).

```
    <?php
       $array1 = array("a" => "verde", "vermelho", "azul");
       $array2 = array("b" => "verde", "amarelo", "vermelho");
       $result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
       print_r($result);
    ?>
```

Caso tenha um vetor de objetos, pode utilizar a funcão abaixo:
Podes ver funcionando [aqui](https://www.ideone.com/HXm2Am)

```
<?php

  $a = array(
      (object) array("id" => 1),
      (object) array("id" => 3),
      (object) array("id" => 5),
      (object) array("id" => 6),
      (object) array("id" => 7)
  );

  $b = array(
      (object) array("id" => 1),
      (object) array("id" => 3),
      (object) array("id" => 5),
      (object) array("id" => 6),

  );

  $result = array_map('unserialize',
      array_intersect(
          array_map('serialize',$a), 
          array_map('serialize',$b)
      )
  );

  print_r($result);

?>
```